# Linked list template implementation and operators overloading

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am pretty new to templates in C++ and I'm having some trouble understanding them for the moment. So, someone gave me the next linked list implementation using templates, and the operators overloading is very unclear for me. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class List;

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const List<T>&);

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T info;
    Node<T>* next;

    Node (T x, Node<T>* n = nullptr) : info(x), next(n) {}
};

template <typename T>

class List {
    Node<T>* first, *last;
    public:
        List() {
            this->first = nullptr;
            this->last = nullptr;
        }

        List (initializer_list<T> l)
        {
            ...
        }
         ~List();

        template <typename U>
                friend istream& operator >>(istream& is, List<U>& l);  /// ***HERE***

        friend ostream& operator<< <T> (ostream&, const List<T>&);     /// ***HERE***
        void insert(T,unsigned);
};
template <typename T> List <T>::~List()
{
   ...
}

template <typename T>
istream& operator >>(istream& is, List<T>& l)
{
    Node<T>* f = l.first;
    while (f != nullptr)
    {
        is >> f->info;
        f = f->next;
    }
    return is;
}

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const List<T>& l) {
    Node<T>* p = l.first;

    while (p != nullptr) {
        out << p->info << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }

    return out;
}
template<typename T>
void List<T>::insert(T t, unsigned x)
{
    ...
}

int main () {
}
```

Why did he use `template <typename U>` for overloading `>>` and `friend ostream& operator<< <T>`  ( I am not sure I even understand what that `<T>` to the right of the `<<` means).

Comment: `ostream& operator<< <T> (ostream&, const List<T>&); ` is an instantiation of the template declared above. Similar to having `template <typename T> void foo();` and then `foo<T>();`. Why the author didnt do the same for `operator>>` is not clear, you have to ask the author.

Comment: You need to study a good reference on the C++ programming language. You could start with: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer to your question can be found in the second edition of [**C++ Templates: The Complete Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714121) on **2.4 Friends** on page 30:

Generally `operator >>` and `<<` is overloaded for standard input `std::istream` and output streams `std::ostream` so you can read from input and write to abstract output streams. This can be done outside of the class but in case the class members that are accessed in the process are **private** (like the two pointers `first` and `last` in your example) one will either have to make an interface for it with setters and getters or **declare the operator as a `friend` inside the class**. Normally one would declare and define it inside the class itself but if for some reason one wishes or needs to do otherwise things become a bit more tricky and there are two main ways of **declaring a friend function but defining it afterwards**:

- One can declare **a new function template with a different template parameter**.

  ```
  template <typename U>
  friend istream& operator >> (istream&, List<U>&);
  ```

  This is the way `friend istream& operator >> (istream&, List<U>&);` is implemented.
- One can **forward-declare the class as well as the output operator**

  ```
  template<typename T> class List;

  template <typename T>
  ostream& operator << (ostream&, const List<T>&);
  ```

  and then we **declare a specialisation of the non-member function template as friend** (therefore with `<T>`).

  ```
  friend ostream& operator << <T> (ostream&, const List<T>&);
  ```

  This is the way `friend ostream& operator << <T> (ostream&, const List<T>&);` is implemented.

In both cases you will have to follow up the declaration by the definition outside of the class.

I do not see a real reason from the code snippet to prefer one over the other: In this context they should be equal. I personally would actually not even go through the hassle of forward-declaring anything and would instead declare and define it inside the class itself as I think it is much more clear. In my opinion forward-declarations should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: "forward-declarations should be avoided whenever possible.".. well, if one can replace including a header with a forward declaration then one should do it. If one doesn't need either, even better